# PyTest parameterizing multiple fixtures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to figure this out in a nice way, but cannot seem to make it work.

Let's say I have the following business logic to test:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def execute(self):
        return self.value
```

and the following test cases:

```
test_cases = [
    {
        'name': "assert True",
        'data': True,
        'expected': False
    }, {
        'name': "assert False",
        'data': False,
        'expected': True
    }
]
```

I'd like then to write the following test suite:

```
def idfn(val):
    return val.get('name')

@pytest.fixture(params=test_cases, ids=idfn)
def my_class(request):
    return MyClass(request.param['data'])


@pytest.fixture(params=test_cases, ids=idfn)
def expected(request):
    return request.param['expected']


class Test():
    def test_execute(self, my_class, expected):
        assert my_class.execute() == expected
```

How do I avoid pytest from doing every possible combination of test case ? I'd like to only generate 2 tests, since I have 2 test cases, but PyTest is generating 4.

[image: pytest test collection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use several coupled parameters (`data` and `expected`), you just have combine them in a single fixture or in a single `parametrize` call, otherwise the fixtures will always be combined as you have seen:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=test_cases, ids=idfn)
def my_class_cases(request):
    return MyClass(request.param['data']), request.param['expected']

class Test:
    def test_execute(self, my_class_cases):
        assert my_class_cases[0].execute() == my_class_cases[1]
```

Or use a dict for readability:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=test_cases, ids=idfn)
def my_class_cases(request):
    return {'class': MyClass(request.param['data']),
            'expected': request.param['expected']}

class Test:
    def test_execute(self, my_class_cases):
        assert my_class_cases['class'].execute() == my_class_cases['expected']
```

In your case, you could also use `mark.parametrize` directly without using a fixture:

```py
def get_test_params():
    return [(MyClass(case['data']), case['expected']) for case in test_cases]

def getids():
    return [case['name'] for case in test_cases]

class Test:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("my_class,data", get_test_params(), ids=getids())
    def test_execute(self, my_class, data):
        assert my_class.execute() == data
```

Which option to use is a matter of taste.
In this case the use of `mark.parametrize` is probably the better option, because the separate arguments make it better readable. A fixture might be the better option if you want to use the parameters in more than one test, and the reading of the testdata is expansive.
Note that there is also the option to parametrize the tests in `pytest_generate_tests`, which has the same effect as adding the `mark.parametrize` decorator to all or some tests.

Comment: Okay, I see what needs to be done. As a follow up question, not using a fixture. When would you use a fixture vs the parameterize ?

Comment: I added a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- So we I have class user with name and age
- Class constructor expecting name and age parameters
- In fixture we have sent parmas as [("swapnil-1",23),("swapnil-2",25)]
- In the fixture body while instantiating user class,
- user(request.param[0],request.param[1]) is used as request.param[0] is passed for name, and request.param[1] for age

```
class user:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
class Test_parameterize:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class',params=[("swapnil-1",25),("swapnil-2",27)])
    def dummy_usr_obj(self, request):
    
         obj = user(request.param[0],request.param[1])
         yield obj
        obj = None

    def test_user(self,dummy_usr_obj):
    
        print("--user name :  {0} user age {1} ".format(dummy_usr_obj.name, dummy_usr_obj.age))
```